# Remove a particular variable from session variable

Tags: java, tomcat

In my web application in some point, I save to the session an object.

```
session.setAttribute("product", product);
```

How can I delete this particular variable? I searched it and i find only `HttpSession.invalidate()`. However this will kill my session.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just as there is

```
session.setAttribute("foo", foo);
```

there is also

```
session.removeAttribute("foo");
```

You wouldn't want to use `session.invalidate()` because that would kill your session and you wouldn't be able to use it afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
session.removeAttribute("product")
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a removeAttribute("name") in the session, you can use that.